# Loop the web crawler,all NA,but normal in step by step

Tags: r, xml, for-loop, web-scraping, web-crawler

My data has 359 fundnames,I use for-loop to get their web code.

I test the loop, and the problem is I get the all NA result .

However, it works on step by step
(eg:query=paste0(fundnames[1,])....query=paste0(fundnames[5,]).

I think the problem is on my loop  but I can't figure out.

```
fundnames=data.frame(c("AIM+Counselor+Series+Trust","AIM+Growth+Series","Fidelity+Investment+Trust","AIM+Growth+Series","Advisors'+Inner+Circle+Fund+II","AIM+Growth+Series"))
code=c()
# Parameters Settings
for (i in nrow(fundnames)){
query=paste0(fundnames[i,])
tail="&owner=exclude&action=getcompany"

result.urls=paste0(paste0("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=",query),tail)
require(xml2) 

html.page = read_html(url(result.urls[1]))
xpath = "//*[@class='companyName']/a"
target = xml_find_all(html.page, xpath) 
title = xml_text(target)##20 results title
title=gsub(" (see all company filings)", "", title, fixed = TRUE)
code[i]=title
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit simplified approach using `rvest`. Get all the `fundnames` as a character vector. Generate all url's to loop upon. From each url get their respective web code.

```
library(rvest)

fundnames <- c("AIM+Counselor+Series+Trust","AIM+Growth+Series",
           "Fidelity+Investment+Trust","AIM+Growth+Series",
           "Advisors+Inner+Circle+Fund+II","AIM+Growth+Series")
all_urls <- paste0("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=", fundnames)

webcodes <- purrr::map_chr(all_urls, ~.x %>% 
            read_html %>%
            html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@class='companyName']/a") %>%
            html_text() %>%
            sub(" (see all company filings)", "", ., fixed = TRUE))

webcodes
#[1] "0001112996" "0000202032" "0000744822" "0000202032" "0000890540" "0000202032"
```

Comment: Thanks your help,it’s more useful than my method.But do you know what”s the problem on my code

Comment: @ChonKitHui okay..I looked at your code now and there are two very small mistakes. 1) `fundnames[5]` is incorrect. Remove `'` from it or copy `fundnames` which I have used in the answer and 2) Your `for` loop should go from `1:nrow(fundnames)` instead of `nrow(fundnames)`.

Comment: Thanks,I knew what is the problem.Due to I have some fund names has no searching result ,I must fill that blank with the NA,but the loop will stop at the no result fundnames.....

Comment: Now I try to use trycatch to test,thanks for your help.

Comment: I really need to look into purrr +

Comment: @QHarr Although, here it isn't doing anything special, just another way to loop. Replace `map_chr` with `sapply`/`lapply` and it will still work the same.